# why I cant see any output on my reactjs app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started my first React lesson but I cant see any output on my localhost(3000), will you pls help me ?

this is my JS code :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react';

const element = React.createElement("div", { id: "title", className: "app-title" }, "this is a test text");

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: follow the newer version. In the newer version, you simply add tags like <div></div> rather then createElement every time

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash, React.createElement is not the old version thing. It is what the actual transpiled react elements will look like.

Comment: @HO33EIN, your code does work. did you set up your project using `npx create-react-app `  command?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera — No it doesn't.

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash my tutorial isnt old, I just tried to create element on this way

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera yes I did

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera yes I mean nowadays we are using simple ```html tags``` rather then ```createElement``` 
@HO33EIN

Comment: @Muhammad Bilal Bangash, yes, it is `jsx` not `html`

Comment: I was checking the code in StackOverflow snippets. and it worked as imports are correct.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera yes exactly and I think ```JSX``` way is easily understandable

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash — JSX needs transpiling into JS before the browser can handle it. It's nicer syntax in the long run, but there's a bunch of prerequisites that some tutorials prefer to teach *after* getting Hello, World working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Console in your browser's developer tools. When I run this code it says:

> Uncaught TypeError: _reactDefault.default.render is not a function

So something is wrong with the object you call `render` on. That clues us into looking at the place it is defined.

> ```
> import React from 'react';
> import ReactDOM from 'react';
> ```

You've imported `react` *twice* and assigned it to different variables. That doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

So go back and check the tutorial you are working from.

You should see that `ReactDOM` should be imported from `'react-dom'` and not `'react'`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```